# Magento - left.ptml not showing on all product list pages

Tags: list, magento, product, php

left.phtml the file that displays the left navigation on a magento page is only showing on one list view page and not the others does anyone have a solution to get that file to show in all list views

Comment: Are you asking about layer naviation???

Answer (score 1):

If you are tasking left.phtml,

Then According `magento structure  left.phtml` are only show for  `Non-Anchor category` in  it `left side of category`.

And `layer navigation`  are only  showing for `Anchor category`.for anchor  left.phtml is not showing.

```
 For non-Anchor categories
```

see catalog.xml  code

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Also for

```
Anchor categories
```

see at catalog.xml

```
 <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Hope ,you will `understand`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the layout in folder theme/package (it can be in default/default, when your theme is in another folder)
2. Check if layout is plugged (use in your layout.xml something like <remove name="header">). If header will be removed - you use correct layout
3. Check the handle and reference name, where you are adding block. For example: you are adding layered navigation block. On one page it placed in handle <catalog_category_layered>, but your page there no this handle. Try to add to <catalog_category_default> or even in <default>.
4. Open your template and check if the block was added there. Look for 
   <?php $this->getChildHtml('blockName'); ?>
5. Try to change your block name (maybe on this page already exist block with the same name)
6. (this option can be useless for you) Please check the block output in system / configuration / advanced
7. Maybe there is a conflict between two navigation modules (for example module A and module B). The module A can use it for rewrite. But the module B will use it only for investigation and use on this page it's own calls. In that case the module A will not work (to resolve this issue you need to change rewrite. class A should rewrite class B)

If you are trying to add navigation to CMS page - try to google this topic (how to add navigation to CMS page). There are many examples and I don't want to duplicate them.